# Stacktrace aware grep

Tags: java, logging, grep, stack-trace

Are there any grep -like Unix/Linux command line tools that understand Java stacktraces in log files that are printed by log4j or logback? The tool should understand that a stacktrace consists of several lines.

Typical use case would be to filter out certain exceptions and corresponding stacktraces when viewing logs that are stored to files.

Comment: Since you mention `grep`, are you on a *nix platform?

Comment: It should be possible to achieve what you want using `sed` or similar utilities but you need to provide some sample data ...

Comment: @devnull: I am using Linux.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, some sample data with expected output might help.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using following sed one line program:

```
sed -nr ':main; /^[0-9 :,-]{23} ERROR / { :loop; p; n; /^[0-9 :,-]{23} / b main; b loop}'
```

The first `[0-9 :,-]{23}` recognizes log record start. Right after it, before the slash, you can write additional regexp to limit which records to print. The expression in `{...}` loops through the following lines until new record header is found.

My program works for logs where log records start with:

```
2015-08-25 12:49:34,906 ...
```

And prints all records with stack traces which has ERROR after record start. Example:

```
2015-08-25 12:49:34,906 ERROR [http-8080-89] [Error@112] NullPointerException:
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
...
```

**The sed program explanation**

> The sed program expression `/regexp/ command` means: if the current line matches the regexp run command.

sed will read the input line and run the program. When the line matches `/^[0-9 :,-]{23} ERROR /` it runs the command block `{...}`, if not then since program ended, sed will not print the current line to output (option -n), then sed reads the next line and run the program again. This repeats until end of input.

`{...}` explanation:

1. `p` - print the current line
2. `n` - read next line
3. `/^[0-9 :,-]{23} / b main` - if the line matches the regexp continue at label `:main` - effectively rerunning the whole program on the current line without reading next line - to not miss next possible exception
4. continue at label `:loop`

So the regexps:

1. `/^[0-9 :,-]{23} ERROR /` matches lines which starts the log record
2. `/^[0-9 :,-]{23} /` matches line which is next log record

Comment: Could you please articulate a little more about how this command works for those of us who aren't experts in sed? I understand the the "b" commands mean essentially "goto" the the specified label. What do the "p" and "n" commands do?

Comment: I updated the answer with explanation of the program. Yet the `n`, `p` commands can be easily found in sed documentation.

Comment: Could this be updated to emit a separator between iterations of the `:main` loop? Tried adding the `i` command but my sed chops are not strong enough

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your question but when I want to get the stacktrace I use `grep -A` to get the lines right after the line I'm looking for.

For example:

 `grep -A 200 "2014-09-08/12:11:36.110" catalina.out`